transpose from one row with set a set of numbers to multiple columns with multiple rows downwards
I'm currently working on how to transpose one row with multiple sets of column that mostly separated with blanks to multiple sets of columns with multiple rows.

when I transpose it, it will become like this. 
what I want is something like this as a final result.
As of now, what I have been doing is that I manually cut & paste to the next row the data.

Is there a possible way or formula?

Two other alternative methods, if one don't have access to PIVOTBY() then:


• Formula used in cell D2
=LET(
     a, A2:B36,
     b, DROP(a,,1),
     c, TOROW(UNIQUE(b),1),
     DROP(REDUCE("",c,LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,
     VSTACK(y,FILTER(A2:A36,B2:B36=y))))),,1))


Or Using Power Query --> paste the following m-code in advanced editor of a blank query, after converting the source range into structured references.


let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Filter = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Progress] <> null and [Progress] <> ""),
    Group = Table.Group(Filter, {"Progress"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Date of Progress=nullable datetime, Progress=text]}}),
    Index = Table.AddColumn(Group, "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"Index",1,1)),
    Remove = Table.SelectColumns(Index,{"Custom"}),
    Expand = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Remove, "Custom", {"Date of Progress", "Progress", "Index"}, {"Date of Progress", "Progress", "Index"}),
    Pivot = Table.Pivot(Expand, List.Distinct(Expand[Progress]), "Progress", "Date of Progress"),
    DataType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Pivot,{{"Date 1", type date}, {"Date 2", type date}, {"Date 3", type date}, {"Date 4", type date}, {"Date 5", type date}, {"Date 6", type date}, {"Date 7", type date}, {"Date 8", type date}}),
    RemovedCols = Table.RemoveColumns(DataType,{"Index"})
in
    RemovedCols



Hi, thanks for your response, now i have more time for other things..

PIVOTBY() may help with few other function. Try-
=DROP(PIVOTBY(MAP(B2:B36,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(B2:x=x)))),B2:B36,A2:A36,MAX,,0,,0,,A2:A36<>""),,1)



Thank you for your response sir but sad to say Im using an older version of excel

Nice way to use filter array A2:A36<>"" and use of MAX is shorter compared to SINGLE, which I used in my attempt having the same approach but I didn't use the filter option which made it way longer and more complicated =LET(x,LAMBDA(y,TOCOL(IFS(LEN(B2:B12),y),2)),z,DROP(PIVOTBY(x(MAP(B2:B12,LAMBDA(b,SUM(N(B2:b=b))))),x(B2:B12),x(A2:A12),SINGLE,,0,,0),,1),IFERROR(IF(z,z,""),z))

@P.b I learned the trick one of your answer few days ago. Thanks for another approach.
